# Can I find Doodles and Grimalkynes in High Rank Quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I've largely neglected searching for the various Doodles and Grimalkynes (aka the cats of the New World) to acquire additional Palico Gadgets. I got the Plunderblade, and never looked back. Now I'm interested in trying out the others. I tried one of the High Rank events, and could not find any Doodles (the "trail" you can research for them). However, I tried again in a Low Rank expedition, found the doodles, and got the gadget I was seeking.

My question is, can I find Doodles or the Grimalkynes of an area in a High Rank quest? If so, are there any other restrictions?

As an addendum, I know the Gajalaka cats' quest in the Elder's Recess would have to be High Rank, but that one is also restricted to being available only after acquiring all the other gadgets.

Comment: Are you asking where to find doodles? Depends on which "kind" of doodles, (the game has several request missions with varying rules). generally, high rank expedition of the map where the request was given is the best place to find them, though.

Comment: @Rapitor I was not asking where specifically on the map to find the doodles, rather, are there certain quests that they don't appear? Also, to whomever downvoted, please let me know what to improve for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't tell you the specifics of each one, its been a while since I did them, but yes, you can find each of the Grimalkyne tribes on High Rank Expeditions. 
I did most of them in High Rank as I had forgotten they'd existed up until then.

In each case you simply need to start an expedition in the region, and just hunt around till you find enough, or until you happen upon whatever triggers the quest/investigation that will unlock the tribe and its item.

Note: It may help to 'pin' the doodles in the map (you can see them in the monster list at the bottom left), though I never used this function so I can't say for sure